# How do I have random spawns occur every so many seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, timer

This is my code, I am very new and don't know what I need to change. I am trying to spawn in knives every so often so my players can pick them up and be able to stab each other for 3 seconds after picking one up. I am able to get the knife to spawn in, but I can get the knife to spawn multiple times, and I definitely can't control how often the knives spawn in. If anyone could look at my code and figuire out what I need to add I would be so thankful.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KnifeSpawns : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Knifeprefab;
public Vector3 center;
public Vector3 size;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    SpawnKnife();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

public void SpawnKnife()
{

    Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x/2, size.x/2),Random.Range(-size.z / 2, 
size.z / 2),Random.Range(-size.y/1,size.y/1));

    Instantiate(Knifeprefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);

}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
    Gizmos.DrawCube(center, size);
}

}
```

Comment: This question doesn't relate to the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag for you. Please be sure to read tag descriptions before you use tags so that you don't inadvertently misuse them (or worse: give misleading information about your question).

Comment: Looking at your code, you're only spawning a knife in the `Start()` method, meaning that `SpawnKnife()` will only be called once. You need to work out some kind of timing mechanism with `Update()` in order to spawn knives at a set interval.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Coroutine to do this. Declare a variable to hold the time interval, a variable to hold number of knives spawned, and a variable to hold how many knives to spawn. Then inside the Coroutine use while loop to control limit of spawning.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KnifeSpawns : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Knifeprefab;
    public Vector3 center;
    public Vector3 size;
    int spawnCount; // how many knives is spawned
    float timeInterval; // to spawn knife every 3 seconds
    int limit; // how many knives to spawn

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spawnCount = 0;
        limit = 10;
        timeInterval = 3f;
        StartCoroutine("SpawnKnife");
    }

    public IEnumerator SpawnKnife()
    {
        while (spawnCount <= limit)
        {
            Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x / 2, size.x / 2), Random.Range(-size.z / 2, size.z / 2), Random.Range(-size.y / 1, size.y / 1));

            Instantiate(Knifeprefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            spawnCount += 1;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeInterval);
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
        Gizmos.DrawCube(center, size);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also directly make `Start` a Coroutine